# SQLite Database Browser shows only the 1st row

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ddms

I'm implementing an Android Application now. 
I made a database in the application, and I tried to check it DDMS and SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1.

The table I created has several rows (I could checked by System.out.println in my program), but only the 1st row is showed in SQLite Database Browser.

The latest updated time of database file which is showed in DDMS is correct.

Please let me know how I can resolve this problem.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.twitterdata);

        helper = new CreateTableHelper(TwitterData.this);

        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Const.PREFERENCE_NAME,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        /**
         * Handle OAuth Callback
         */
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(Const.CALLBACK_URL)) {
            String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(Const.IEXTRA_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
            try {
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                        requestToken, verifier);

                User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();

                List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user
                        .getScreenName());

                for (Status status : statuses) {
                    String tweet = status.getText();
                    String[] words = tweet.split(" ");

                    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                        if (words[i].length() > 1) {
                            String requestURL = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&format=json&clshow=!hidden&cllimit=10&titles="
                                    + words[i];

                            URL wikiRequest = new URL(requestURL);
                            URLConnection connection = wikiRequest
                                    .openConnection();
                            connection.setDoOutput(true);

                            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
                                    wikiRequest.openStream());
                            String response = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z")
                                    .next();
                            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                            JSONObject query = json.getJSONObject("query");
                            JSONObject pages_jsn = query.getJSONObject("pages");
                            String pages = query.getString("pages");

                            int dqm_cnt = 0;
                            int dqm_while = 0;
                            String page_id_str = "";
                            Character dq = pages.charAt(0);
                            while (dqm_cnt < 2) {
                                Character tmp = pages.charAt(dqm_while);
                                if (tmp.equals(dq)) {
                                    dqm_cnt++;
                                }
                                try {
                                    Integer.parseInt(tmp.toString());
                                    page_id_str += tmp;
                                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                }
                                dqm_while++;
                            }

                            int page_id = Integer.parseInt(page_id_str);

                            // The article is available.
                            if (page_id != 1) {
                                JSONObject pageidjson = pages_jsn
                                        .getJSONObject(page_id_str);
                                db.beginTransaction();
                                try {
                                    // category is available
                                    String tmp_interest = pageidjson
                                            .getString("title");
                                    JSONArray categories_array = pageidjson
                                            .getJSONArray("categories");

                                    // interests
                                    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
                                    String[] i_columns = { "id", "name",
                                            "count" };
                                    SQLiteCursor ic = (SQLiteCursor) db.query(
                                            "interests", i_columns, "name = '"
                                                    + tmp_interest + "'", null,
                                            null, null, null);
                                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                                    db.endTransaction();

                                    if (ic.getCount() == 0) {
                                        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                                        db.beginTransaction();

                                        ContentValues val_interest = new ContentValues();
                                        val_interest.put("name", tmp_interest);
                                        val_interest.put("count", 1);
                                        db.insert("interests", null,
                                                val_interest);
                                        System.out.println("successfully inserted " + tmp_interest);
                                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                                        db.endTransaction();
                                    } else {
                                        ic.moveToFirst();
                                        int i_id = ic.getInt(0);
                                        db.beginTransaction();
                                        ContentValues db_i_val = new ContentValues();
                                        db_i_val.put("count", ic.getInt(2) + 1);
                                        db.update("interests", db_i_val, "id = "
                                                + i_id, null);
                                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                                        db.endTransaction();

                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
                                }
                            }

                            scanner.close();

                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName()
                            + " - " + status.getText());
                }
                db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
                String[] i_columns = { "id", "name",
                        "count" };
                SQLiteCursor test = (SQLiteCursor) db.query(
                        "interests", i_columns, null, null,
                        null, null, null);
                System.out.println("Table Interests has " + test.getColumnCount() + "rows");

                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                db.endTransaction();

                db.close();

                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                e.putString(Const.PREF_KEY_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(Const.PREF_KEY_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                e.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

**Solve**

- Use `System.out.println("Table Interests has " + test.getCount() + "rows");` instead of  `System.out.println("Table Interests has " + test.getColumnCount() + "rows");`

Then I can get a correct number of rows.

- I should to be careful the position of `db.beginTransaction()`. Im my cord, there is `try` between `db.beginTransaction()` and `db.endTransaction()`. That did not work correctly.

Comment: Also FYI, you should be breaking up your code into more methods. This is quite messy.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I'll rewrite my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
System.out.println("Table Interests has " + test.getColumnCount() + "rows");
```

This will print the number of columns.

You should be using:

```
System.out.println("Table Interests has " + test.getCount() + "rows");
```

**Documentation**
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html#getCount()

Comment: Thanks! I correct my code, and then it noticed that `Table Interests has 83rows` . 

But SQLite Database Browser shows only the 1st row still, so I cannot check the content of the database yet...

Comment: Post where you are trying to access the rows and expect results.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Finally, I could resolve my problem.